# Understanding a Proof that for Group $G$ Generated by 2 Elements with exp($G$)=3, $G$ is Finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The following is a proof:

[image]

I am having trouble understanding the proof. First, why is it sufficient to prove that any element has a representation of length $<12$? Secondly, why can we assume the all $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ are $\pm 1$? What about an element that is just strictly powers of $a$? How can we represent that if we always have some $b$ or its inverse in between $a$'s? Should't we need zero powers? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a representation of bounded length - say $\le 12$, you can count the number of possible elements by listing the representations of length $12$ or less. The empty sequence is (should be) included to get the identity. Some of these may be equal, but that will reduce the number of distinct elements, and so the number of elements in the group is therefore finite.

If everything is a power of $a$ you get a representation of length $1$, or $0$ if you reduce to the identity.

We have $a^3=1$ so that $a^{-1}=a^2=a^5= \dots$; $a^1=a^4=a^7 \dots$. $0$ is excluded because $1=a^0=a^3=a^6 \dots$ and this term drops out. So whatever power of $a$ you have it reduces to the identity or to the power $\pm 1$ simply by using the relation $a^3=1$.

Comment: so the choice of 12 is arbitrary?

Comment: The number 12 was chosen since you need at least 12 elements on the second to last row for the substitution to work. (The first 12 elements form the 3rd power of an element, hence you can replace it by 1 and make the representation shorter.)

Comment: Of course you can also choose a larger number instead of 12, but it just makes counting the possible representations more cumbersome. It's natural to choose the smallest possible bound, which is 12.

Comment: @Kaiwen The choice of $12$ is because the restrictions on elements generate a repeating pattern of length $4$, and if this repeats three times it is a cube and can be replaced by $1$. This isn't a number you can guess at the beginning of the proof without knowing how it works out - the strategy here is to force a repeating pattern to repeat three times, so that the string can be shortened. As the string gets longer this becomes impossible to avoid. When you know this you can put a bound on the length of the string. When you can bound the length you can show that the group is finite.

Comment: @Kaiwen The proof as presented is tidied up from how you would first work it out.